# Reading multiple JSON files and appending to a dataset using Python / Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

Here is the code I am trying to run to read multiple JSON files from my directory. <file_names> contains the names of all the files I am trying to read.

```html
for file in range(1, len(file_names)):
    data = pd.read_json(file_names[number])
    df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
```

I am getting the following error:

*ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index*

Comment: kindly share the format of 1 json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like you've defined number. Also  you can speed this up by waiting to concatenate dfs at the end.

Try this assuming file_names is list and pd.read_json() works as expected.

```
df_hold_list = [] # appending dataframe on each loop is a lot of overhead, so collect them first
for file in file_names:
    df_hold_list.append(pd.read_json(file))

df = pd.concat(df_hold_list, axis=0) # check the axis, either 1 or 0 depending on how you want it to look
```